# Can we define probability measures $\text P_x$ on $C([0,\infty))$ such that the coordinate process is a Brownian motion started at $x$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, solution-verification, brownian-motion

Let $(W_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a continuous Brownian motion on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ and $$\pi_t:C([0,\infty))\to\mathbb R\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto x(t)$$ for $t\ge0$. Equip $C([0,\infty))$ with the topology of compact convergence. Then $$\mathcal B(C([0,\infty))=\sigma\left(\pi_t,t\ge0\right)\tag1$$ and hence $W:\Omega\to C([0,\infty))$ is $\left(\mathcal A,\mathcal B(\tau)\right)$-measurable.

> So, the process $(\pi_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a Brownian motion on $(C[0,\infty),\mathcal B(C[0,\infty)),\operatorname P_0)$, where $\operatorname P_0:=\operatorname P\circ\:W^{-1}$.
>
> Now it is tempting to consider for every $x\in\mathbb R$ a separate continuous Brownian motion *started in $x$* and obtain probability measure $\operatorname P_x$ on $(C[0,\infty),\mathcal B(C[0,\infty))$ in this way.
>
> **Question**: Are we able to do this such that the map $x\mapsto\operatorname P_x(B)$ is Borel measurable for all $B\in\mathcal B(C([0,\infty))$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define $\operatorname P_x$ to be the image of $\operatorname P_0$ under the translation $w\mapsto w+x:=\{w(t)+x, t\ge 0\}$ on $C[0,\infty)$, then $x\mapsto \operatorname P_x$ is Borel measurable, in the sense that $x\mapsto\int F(w)\operatorname P_x(dw)$ is Borel measurable for each bounded $\mathcal B(C[0,\infty))$-measurable function $F$. Indeed, $x\mapsto\int F(w)\operatorname P_x(dw)$ is continuous if $F$ has the form
$$
F(w)=f_1(w(t_1))f_2(w(t_2))\dots f_n(w(t_n)),
$$
with $n$ a positive integer, $0\le t_1<t_2<\dots <t_n$ and each $f_k$ bounded and continuous. The asserted measurability then follows for general bounded measurable $F$ by a monotone class argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see. The same should hold in more generality for any continuous group operation on a metrizable group. However, while this should be easy, I'm struggling to see how we see the continuity. Please take a look at the separate question I've asked on that: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4104372/47771.

Comment: [It seems like](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4104425/47771) I'm missing something here. With the notation of the other question, let $\kappa(x,\;\cdot\;):=\mu\circ\tau_x^{-1}$. Then $\kappa f$ is clearly continuous for all bounded continuous $f$. By the same reasoning, I see that your claim for all $F$ of the presented form is true. But how do you apply a monotone class argument and why wouldn't that argument be incorrect in the context of the other question?

Comment: For $F$ of the indicated form, $\int F d\operatorname P_x$ is a continuous, hence measurable function of $x$. The class of functions $F$ of the indicated form is closed under the formation of products, and generates $\mathcal B(C[0,\infty))$. By the functional form of the monotone class theorem (see Theorem 1 at https://almostsuremath.com/2019/10/27/the-functional-monotone-class-theorem/), $x\mapsto\int F d\operatorname P_x$ is Borel measurable for each bounded measurable $F$.

This argument is  general, and works for continuous group actions. I've addressed your other question separately.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Everything is clear to me, but why does this class generate $\mathcal B(C[0,\infty))$? And if you take a look at the functional monotone class theorem as stated here https://planetmath.org/functionalmonotoneclasstheorem, why do the indicator functions belong to that class? (It's clear to me that the projections $\omega\mapsto\omega(t)$ are continuous for all $t$.)

Comment: The class contains the indicator of each event of the form $\{w: w(t)\in U\}$ for each $t\ge 0$ and each open $U$—approximate the indicator of $U$ from below by a sequence of continuous functions. 

Theorem 2 on the page  you cite is the form of the functional MCT I had in mind. The variant Theorem 1 is not useful in the present context.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort so far. Please take a look at [my answer below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4105395/47771). Did I miss anything or do you agree?

Comment: I'd really interested in your thoughts. Could you take a brief look?

Answer (score 0):

Let us step backward for a moment and think about what we really need to obtain the claim:

### **Step 1**

Let $(G,\mathcal G)$ be a measurable group, $$\tau_x:G\to G\;,\;\;\;y\mapsto y+x$$ for $x\in G$, $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(G,\mathcal G)$ and $$\kappa(x,\;\cdot\;):=\tau_x(\mu).$$ By the very definition of a measurable group, $$\theta:G^2\to G\;,\;\;\;(x,y)\mapsto x+y$$ is $(\mathcal G^{\otimes2},\mathcal G)$-measurable. Thus, if $B\in\mathcal G$, then $A:=\theta^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal G^{\otimes2}$ and $$\kappa(\;\cdot\;,B)=\int\mu({\rm d}y)1_A(y,\;\cdot\;)\tag2$$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable by Fubini's theorem. So, $\kappa$ is a Markov kernel on $(G,\mathcal G)$.

### Step 2

Now let $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $(G,\mathcal G)$-valued Lévy process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ and $$\kappa_t(x,\;\cdot\;):=\mathcal L(X_t+x)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in G\text{ and }t\ge0.$$ If $$\mu_t:=\mathcal L(X_t)\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0,$$ we see that $$\tau_x(\mu_t)=\mathcal L(X_t+x)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag3$$ and, by step 1, $\kappa_t$ is a Markov kernel on $(G,\mathcal G)$ for all $t\ge0$. (Actually, $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a convolution semigroup on $(G,\mathcal G)$.)

### Step 3

Now let $$\rho(x,B):=\operatorname P\left[(X_t)_{t\ge0}+x\in B\right]\;\;\;\text{for }(x,B)\in G\times\mathcal G^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)}.$$

In order to show that $\rho$ is a Markov kernel, let $$\tilde\tau_x:G^{[0,\:\infty)}\to G^{[0,\:\infty)}\;,\;\;\;(y_t)_{t\ge0}\mapsto(y_t+x)_{t\ge0}.$$ As in the question, let $$\pi_t:G^{[0,\:\infty)}\to G\;,\;\;\;y\mapsto y_t$$ for $t\ge0$. Since $\mathcal G^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)}=\sigma(\pi_t,t\ge0)$, for every $x\in G$, the map $\tilde\tau_x$ should be $\mathcal G^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)},\mathcal G^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)})$-measurable if and only if $\tilde\tau_x^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal G^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)}$ for every $B$ of the form $B=(\pi_{t_1},\ldots,\pi_{t_n})^{-1}(A)$, where $A\in\mathcal G^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)}$, $n\in\mathbb N$ and $0\le t_1<\cdots<t_n$. But that's clearly the case, since $\tau_x$ is $(\mathcal G,\mathcal G)$-measurable.

### **Step 4**

In the context of the question, the topology of compact convergence on $\mathbb R^{[0,\:\infty)}$ is metrizable by a metric $d$ and hence $(\mathbb R^{[0,\:\infty)},d)$ is a measurable group. So, step 3 immediately yields the desired result, but with $C([0,\infty))$ replaced by $\mathbb R^{[0,\:\infty)}$.

However, since $\mathcal B(C([0,\infty)),d)=\sigma(\left.\pi_t\right|_{C([0,\:\infty))})$, everything I wrote in step 3 should still hold when $\mathbb R^{[0,\:\infty)}$ is replaced by $C([0,\infty)$.

> I would highly appreciate if someone could verify if I made any mistake in my reasoning above!

Comment: In Step 4, how do you show that $(\Bbb R^{[0,\infty)},d)$ is a measurable group? Is this even  necessary — why not just stick with $C[0,\infty)$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins Every metric vector space is a measurable group. However, for simplicity, replace "measurable group" by "normed vector space" (and take $\mathcal G$ to be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra) at every stage above. Do you agree then?

Comment: A second countable topological group is  a measurable group, okay.  But $(\Bbb R^\infty,d)$ is not second countable.

Comment: @JohnDawkins I'm not sure why we need second-countability, but again: Do you agree if we replace $(G,\mathcal G)$ by a normed space with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: I agree if it's a separable Banach space, for example.  You're trying to deduce the measurability of the group operations from their continuity. One route to this is second countability. The problem being that in general (for a topological group $G$) the Borel $\sigma$-field on $\mathcal B(G\times G)$ is strictly bigger than $\mathcal B(G) \otimes\mathcal B(G)$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Why does the space need to be complete? Assume $G$ is a separable normed space. Then $(G^{[0,\:\infty)},d)$ should be separable as well. Let $\pi_t:C([0,\infty),G)\to G$; $x\mapsto x(t)$ for $t\ge0$. The crucial thing to show should be $\mathcal B(C([0,\infty),G),d)=\sigma(\pi_t,t\ge0)$. Since $\pi_t$ is $(d,\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_G)$-continuous for all $t\ge0$, the inclusion "$\supseteq$" holds even without separability.

Comment: @JohnDawkins For the other inclusion "$\subseteq$", since $(C([0,\infty),G),d)$ is separable, every open subset is the countable union of open balls. It's therefore sufficient to show that for every $y\in C([0,\infty),G)$, the map $\left.d(\;\cdot\;,y)\right|_{C([0,\:\infty),\:G)}$ is $(\mathcal B(C([0,\infty),G),d),\mathcal B(G))$-measurable, which is easy to conclude by considering the explicit form of $d$: $$d(x,y):=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\frac{\overline\rho_k(x,y)}{2^k}\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in G^{[0,\:\infty)},$$

Comment: @JohnDawkins where $$\overline\rho_k(x,y):=1\wedge\sup_{t\in[0,\:k]}\left\|x(t)-y(t)\right\|_G\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in G^{[0,\:\infty)}$$ for $k\in\mathbb N$. We simply need to observe that $$\left.\overline\rho_k(\;\cdot\;,y)\right|_{C([0,\:\infty),\:G)}=1\wedge\sup_{t\in[0,\:k]\:\cap\:\mathbb Q}\left\|\left.\pi_t\right|_{C([0,\:\infty),\:G)}-\pi_t(y)\right\|_G$$ is $(\mathcal B(C([0,\infty),G),d),\mathcal B(G))$-measurable for all $k\in\mathbb N$ and $$\left.d(\;\cdot\;,y)\right|_{C([0,\:∞),\:G)}=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\frac{\left.\overline\rho_k(\;\cdot\;,y)\right|_{C([0,\:∞),\:G)}}{2^k}.$$

Comment: @JohnDawkins (And the same reasoning works if $G$ is not a normed space, but merely a metric space.) Is there anything I'm missing or you worry about?

Comment: Completeness isn't needed — "Banach space" was an *example*. Otherwise, your reasoning seems okay.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thank you for your feedback. Just to be sure, our discussion in the last comments where only about the construction on the space $C([0,\infty),G)$, right? If we instead consider the superset $G^{[0,\:\infty)}$ as in my answer above, then everything holds for an arbitrary measurable group. Or do you think there are some issues in that case as well?