# If $\tau_x(y)=y+x$ and $\mu$ is a measure, then $x\mapsto(\mu\circ\tau_x^{-1})(B)$ is continuous

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, convolution

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric $\mathbb R$-vector space, $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal B(E))$ and $$\tau_x:E\to E\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto y+x$$ for $x\in E$.

> How can we show that $$E\to[0,1]\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto(\mu\circ\tau_x^{-1})(B)=\mu(B-x)\tag1$$ is continuous for all $B\in\mathcal B(E)$?

I'm not sure how I should approach this. Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq E$ and $x\in E$ with $d(x_n,x)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}$. Maybe we can show that $$1_{B-x_n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1_{B-x}\tag2,$$ from which the claim clearly would follow.

$d$ is clearly (jointly) continuous; and $$\theta:E^2\to E\;,\;\;\;(x,y)\mapsto x+y$$ is (jointly) continuous as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false, by example take the Dirac measure concentrated at zero, then

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\delta (\{0\}-1/n)=0\neq \delta (\{0\}-0)=1
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried to generalize the context of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4103551/47771) and was so sure that the claim holds in this generality that I didn't thought on such a simple counterexample. Could you please take a look at the other answer and tell me (if you know) what I'm missing?

Comment: @0xbadf00d sorry but I never learn something about Brownian motion

Comment: The question is not really on Brownian motion, but why the same claim holds in that context by a monotone class argument. The only thing which is relevant in the other question is that we consider a process with continuous paths and hence may consider it as a random variable taking values in $C([0,\infty))$.

Answer (score 0):

Translation continuity, even for open, sets is a strong property. In fact, if $\mu$ is a probability measure on the Borel subsets of the real line such that $x\mapsto\mu(U+x)$ is continuous for each *open* set, then $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure (and conversely). For this and extensions to more general translations, see the paper
"A note on translation continuity of probability measures" [Ann. Probab. 20 (1992), no. 1, 410–420] by S. Zabell.  If $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with a *continuous* density, then $x\mapsto\mu(x+B)$ is continuous for all Borel sets. I don't know what the optimal converse is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you know from my other question, continuity is not necessarily what I'm interested, it would just be a nice shortcut to show measurability, which is what I'm actually after. So, is the map $(1)$ at least measurable? For example, I've found several references (in the context of the construction of a Brownian motion) which claim that $x\mapsto\delta_x\ast\mathcal N_{0,\:t}$ is measurable and this is clearly an instance of the situation in the question (noting that $\delta_x\ast\mu=\mu\circ\tau_x^{-1}$).

Comment: $x\mapsto \mu(x+B)$ is always Borel measurable, for each probability measure $\mu$ and each Borel set $B$. (Monotone class proof as before.) When $\mu$ is a normal distribution, it's even continuous.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess it's really trivial, but how do you see that $x\mapsto\mu(x+B)$ is measurable? I don't see how a monotone class argument helps, since we are ready considering the indicator functions $1_B$.

Comment: As in my answer to your other question, if $f$ is bounded and continuous, then $x\mapsto \int_{\Bbb R} f(t-x)\mu(dt)$ is continuous (dominated convergence), hence Borel measurable.
By the functional MCT, this map is Borel measurable for each bounded measurable $f$. Now take $f=1_B$, in which case  $\int_{\Bbb R} f(t-x)\mu(dt)=\mu(x+B)$.

Comment: Please take a look at [Schilling's paper on Lévy processes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.00251.pdf#page=27). In the proof of Lemma 4.4, he claims that (the proof of) Fubini's theorem would allow to conclude the measurability for the transition semigroup of a Lévy process. Does this refer to an alternative proof of the claim or does it essentially boil down to the version of the monotone class theorem that you've got in mind?

Comment: I really would like to know this, because your argument (since it considers *continuous* functions) won't work in more general contexts (where the measure space is not a topological space with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra) and Fubini's theorem holds on arbitrary measurable spaces.

Comment: Schilling's proof via Fubini rests on the knowledge that $(x,y)\mapsto 1_B(x+y)$ is jointly measurable (for Borel $B$). This in turn uses that fact that $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ is measurable. How you know this depends on the context.